# Variables inside a class is not accessible in method

Tags: php, laravel

I declared a variable outside function methods in a class.
And i changed the value by sending ajax request. The request is fine.
but when i echo the variable name, it still returns null and it doesn't changed at all. How can i properly change it?

here is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use DB;
use App\Helpers\globalFunction;

class registerController extends Controller
{
    public $documentType;
    public $trackingNumber;
    public $recipient;
    public $description;
    public $myvalue = 'hello';

    public function pendingDataBeforeSave(Request $request)
    {
        $this->documentType = $request->documentType;
        $this->trackingNumber = $request->trackingNumber;
        $this->recipient = $request->recipient;
        $this->description = $request->description;
        $this->myvalue = 'new one';
    }

    public function storeSend(Request $request)
    {
        $office = $request->office;
        $sendTo = $request->sendTo;
        $status = $request->status;
        $message = $request->message;
        echo json_encode($this->documentType);
    }
}
```

Heres the client side for function storeSend()

```
var object = {
    office: officeDropdown.value,
    sendTo: senderDropdown.value,
    status: statusDropdown.value,
    message: message.value
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "/sendData");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.head.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']").content);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(object));
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
```

and heres the client side code for function pendingDataBeforeSave

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var object = {
    documentType: documentType.value,
    trackingNumber: trackingNumber.value,
    recipient: recipient.value,
    description: description.value
};

xhr.open("POST", "/pendingDataBeforeSave");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.head.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']").content);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(object));
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        alert('sent');
    } else {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the whole class? How are you calling the `storeSend` and `pendingDataBeforeSave` methods?

Comment: by ajax request. I'm sending request in from client then, the route is
Route::post('/pendingDataBeforeSave', 'registerController@pendingDataBeforeSave');

and 

Route::post('/sendData', 'registerController@storeSend');

Comment: If you show little snippets like that, we have no way of knowing how you have really coded this class. So please remember the need for a [Minimal, **Complete** and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited my code. I posted my whole class.

Comment: Please take a look at some changes

Answer (score 0):

The whole class isn't required since the class is being initiated with each call and the previously set values, in `Route::post('/pendingDataBeforeSave', 'registerController@pendingDataBeforeSave'`, are not being retained when the following, `Route::post('/sendData', 'registerController@storeSend');` is being called.

Not unless there is a mechanism, in which values are being stored across the different requests, of which, have not been mentioned in here?

Comment: The issue is that the state of the class and its contents, cannot be stored across two different Ajax calls, they are stateless. Basically, they create a copy of the class with each request, therefore the variables in the second call are not defined. This can be proved by adding a constructor to the class and setting the variables to a value. The same value will come through in the second Ajax request.

Comment: Perhaps you need to store the information in a session variable in order for it to be accessed by different Ajax requests?

Comment: how can i do it? do you have example code to construct? i tried it already but i got error. and here's my code.

public function __construct($documentType, $trackingNumber) {
   $this->documentType = $documentType;
   $this->trackingNumber = $trackingNumber;
 }

Comment: Aye I certainly do indeed mean the session. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. thank you for making me understand the client and server clearly and better.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at it, the two methods are handled by two different routes. The way PHP works, once the first request has finished it will not persist the property values across multiple requests.

Comment: so it will not save the data i stored from the first request?

Comment: You aren't saving the data, you are setting the values and then discarding the class at the end of the Ajax request (when the data is fed back to the client). You then create a new class with your second Ajax request.

Comment: No. There is no persistence across multiple requests built into PHP.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear to me. I'm facing it for 6hours.